# Community Wiki post on interpreting GRE scores?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

In response to [this meta question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/what-should-we-do-with-the-can-i-get-into-x-program-with-3-xx-gpa/4248#4248), I decided to create a [generic question and answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/114130/is-a-general-gre-score-of-x-sufficient-for-entry-to-postgraduate-degree-y) for posts that ask whether a particular GRE score is good enough for entry to a particular degree.  The goal of the generic Q&A is to subsume a number of specific questions on this topic that can be generalised to a generic answer that would be useful to a broad class of users.  User [scaaahu](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/546/scaaahu) has suggested that this should be a Community Wiki question, and has suggested I see if there is a consensus on meta to transfer this to the Community Wiki.

**Question:** Should this [generic question and answer on evaluating GRE scores](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/114130/is-a-general-gre-score-of-x-sufficient-for-entry-to-postgraduate-degree-y) be turned into a Community Wiki question?

Comment: To clarify, I actually voted to close the question on the main site because it is very institute dependent. Some schools don't even need GRE. Some have different threshold. So, I am not even sure we should have this question in the first place. If we do, I think it should be a CW.

Comment: @scaaahu: Fair enough.  My view is that if the question deals with one aspect of the factor-dependency (i.e., adjusting for the differences between fields) then that is making a contribution to making a more objective answer that is less dependent on particular factors.  Effects of other factors can either be dealt with in other answers, or left as speculation.  Best not to make the perfect the enemy of the good!

Comment: Exactly because you mention different fields in the question, I recommend the CW because it may make the question too broad.

Comment: CW would be fine with me.  It would just be nice to have a Q&A to point to when we get a question asking about a specific GRE score.